# regular expression in java gui for text box

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to perform user input on textbox to check whether they had enter any number or special character in the textbox for their username. I check several resource at online also not able to find out what is my problem inside my code. it's showing me four error message 
 
1) error: 'else' without 'if'

```
 else if(tf3.getText().isEmpty())
```

2.)  error: ';' expected

```
if(!(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")),tf3.getText())
```

3.) error: variable declaration not allowed here

```
if(!(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")),tf3.getText())
```

4.) error: ';' expected

```
if(!(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")),tf3.getText())
```

Here is my full program for my whole program

```
 if(e.getSource()== btn2)
       {

        if(!(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")),tf3.getText())
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a valid name");
         }
         else if(tf3.getText().isEmpty())
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Check your name");
         }
         else if(tf2.getText().isEmpty())
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Check your id");
         }
         else if(cmb1.getSelectedIndex()== 0)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Check your year");
         }
         else if(cmb2.getSelectedIndex()== 0)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Check your major");
         }
         else if(cmb3.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
         {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Check your selection");
         }
         else
         {
         String name = tf3.getText();
         String id = tf2.getText();
         String job = String.valueOf(cmb1.getSelectedIndex());
         String country = String.valueOf(cmb2.getSelectedIndex());
         String software = String.valueOf(cmb3.getSelectedIndex());
         runCC(software,id,name,job,country);
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses:

```
if(!(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")),tf3.getText())
```

should look like:

```
if(!Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$", tf3.getText()))
```

At least if i got what you meant.

Comment: ok, I think it reduce my error ,so do I need to declare the pattern variable, it show me the pattern have error, because from what I seen in online, the pattern need to declare as a variable right ?

Comment: hi,piezol, I solve my problem because I undeclared something within it but why when I key in the alphabet in the text field ,It show me please enter a valid name, it should be accept the input since it's only contain alphabet

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm unable to understand your english.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(!(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")),tf3.getText())
```

to

```
if (! Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$", tf3.getText()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I'm unable to understand what your comments under my answer mean, (not only because i'm drunk!), I'll provide a 'step by step' whats-goin-on:

[Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) provides a static method: [Pattern#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence))
It takes two arguments:

First - a string with a regular expression you want to test your string with
Second - a string to test that regex with.

So, whenever you are calling method:

```
Pattern.matches(regex, string)
```

You're asking, whether:
"string" matches regular expression "regex"

So in your code you want to say:

"Ok, i want to know, if the text inside tx3 field contains only characters, that are between a-z or between A-Z.

So your regex is: "any sequence of characters, that are between a-z or between A-Z.

That corresponds to

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Now, you call the method that will check, whether your strings matches that regex:

```
Pattern.matches("%[a-zA-Z]+$", tx3.getText())
```

That method returns boolean: true, if it matches, or false otherwise.

I don't think anyone will be able to put this more straight-forward.